# I want to check whether one column values are present in another sheets column in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

There is a column in one of my sheet with 30 locations each location having 12 codes Ex

```
LOC CODE
1     A
1     B
1     C 
1     D
2     A
2     B
2     C
2     D
```

There is another sheet with only one column

```
CODE 
A 
B
C
D
```

I want to find out whether the all codes in 2nd column of first sheet are present in second sheet. Also I want to know whether all the codes in sheet 2 are present in sheet 1 or not. How can I do that in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your codes be in `Sheet1` in column `B`, and in `Sheet2` in range `A1:A10`, then:

**1)**

> I want to find out whether the all codes in 2nd column of first sheet are present in second sheet.

```
=SUM(IF(Sheet1!B:B<>"",ISNA(MATCH(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet2!A1:A10,0))*1))=0
```

**2)**

> Also I want to know whether all the codes in sheet 2 are present in sheet 1

```
=SUM(IF(Sheet2!A1:A10<>"",ISNA(MATCH(Sheet2!A1:A10,Sheet1!B:B,0))*1))=0
```

Both formulas returns `TRUE`/`FALSE`

**NOTE**, since it's **array formulas** you should evaluate them by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know not just that all are present but which, if any, are not then a formula such as:

```
=IF(MATCH(B2,Sheet1!B:B,0)>0,"present")
```

in C2 and copied down may suit, assuming your codes are in ColumnB in each sheet and that `Sheet1` is adjusted to suit. Where not present the result would show `#N/A`.